# Why does sscanf ignore the specified width?

Tags: c++, hex, scanf

I'm using this code to convert a hex string with fixed size 32 to a 16 byte uint8 array.

```
const uint8_t* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
uint8_t Bytes[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    sscanf (&c[2*i], "%2hhx", &(Bytes[i]));
}
```

Despite the `hh` specifying a target width of 1 byte, 4 bytes get written per step. Thus, the code writes 3 bytes past the end of the buffer. Why is that?

(For now, I fixed it using a temporary int that gets copied to the array on each step.)

To reproduce:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>

void main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
    uint8_t b[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        b[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sscanf (&c[2*i], "%2hhx", &(b[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout,  "%02x\n", (int)(b[i]));
    }
}
```

The expected output is
01
23
45
67
89
ab
cd
ef
01
23
45
67
89
ab
cd
ef
10
11
12
13

However, the actual output using Visual Studio 2010 is:

01
23
...
cd
ef
00
00
00
13

Comment: What compiler, platform, OS ?

Comment: @PaulR: Why did you change the code? Please describe the rationale.

Comment: @phresnel: He spotted and fixed my mistake :)

Comment: @phresnel: because there was a small typo - I thought it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: hh is C99, not implemented by MSVC.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs: Why did you add the C-tag? This basically held me off proposing to use iostreams instead.

Comment: There you go. The question, as it was when I tagged it, was a c code, too. They edited it afterwards, got to be C++. Feel free proposing iostreams. I would've done that too. I decided to add "c" tag to get this question a bit more eyes. (As if the OP was interested both in c and c++ solutions.) Now, I removed "c" tag.

Comment: @phresnel can you please add an iostream solution, too?

Comment: @phresnel I added the iostream solution, as you requested. It is a bit more lengthy than I expected, due to interesting issues with iostreams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small problem with your code right in the beginning.

```
const uint8_t* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
```

In C++, it is not specified whether a `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`. More precisely, the types
`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` are distinct, and in fact you have to take this into account
when overloading functions and specializing templates.

The code now is:

```
const char* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
uint8_t Bytes[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    sscanf (&c[2*i], "%2hhx", &(Bytes[i]));
}
```

Let us analyse your format string:

```
2  : maximum field witdh to be read
hh : expecting a pointer to signed or unsigned char
x  : means unsigned hex-input

(http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)
```

With this info, it looks correct so far.

From what I can tell, there is no problem **in a C99 conforming library** <sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup>: In this regard, the MSVC library does not support the `hh` specifier.

Comment: Thank you for the insight about un/signed chars

Comment: @mafutrct: Possibly added the solution. `hh` is C99, and MSVC is not fully C99 compliant. Btw, have you tried iostreams already?

Comment: @phresnel: Printing the return-value from `sscanf` does not tell anything about the number of bytes written, as it indicates the number of fields `sscanf` successfully converted. It should always be 1 if there is only one format specifier.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I've confused this with `printf`, thanks for noting me.

Comment: Neither GCC nor Clang conform to C99.  They just "mostly" support it.  The particular issue here is also really a library issue, not an issue with the compiler.

Comment: MS also released a statement that they were not planning on fully supporting C99 and were concentrating on C++ (though I can seem to find the statement now).

Comment: this is nasty. i got stack corruption because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I built and ran the following code using gcc 4.2.1 on Mac OS X:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
    uint8_t b[20] = { 0 };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        b[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sscanf (&c[2*i], "%2hhx", &b[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to behave as expected:

```
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
$ gcc -Wall scanf_hex.c
$ ./a.out 
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef10111213
$
```

Please try building and running the above code with your compiler etc so that we can see if it's a possible compiler/library bug or whether it's some other problem in your code. (You might want to try both debug and release builds.)

Comment: The output was correct. However, a step by step debug showed the known mistaken behavior. I'll edit the question to show.

Comment: Have now added your initialisation loop just to confirm that this still behaves as expected with gcc 4.2.1.

Comment: Yes, it appears this is a flaw in MSVC due to lack of C99 support. GCC seems to comply with C99 far more.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    const char* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
    unsigned char Bytes[16];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {   
            sscanf (&c[2*i], "%2hhx", &(Bytes[i]));
    }   
    for (i=0; i < 16; ++i)
    {   
        fprintf(stdout,  "%02x\n", (int)(Bytes[i]));
    }   
}
```

Useing:

```
> gcc gh.c 
> ./a.out
01
23
45
67
89
ab
cd
ef
01
23
45
67
89
ab
cd
ef
```

Comment: (From this code, it's not possible to tell if the described bug happened)

Answer (score 1):

The c++ solution **with iostream** might be the following:

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<sstream>
  #include<iomanip>      
  using namespace std;

  //...

  const char* c = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";
  unsigned char Bytes[16];
  stringstream s_in(c);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
  {
      string s;
      s_in >> setw(2) >> s;
      unsigned int t;
      stringstream(s) >> hex >> t;
      Bytes[i] = t;
  }
```

Note that s_in does not want to obey to setw(2) if the variable type is not a string. 
Also the width is 1 *by all means* if the variable is of type char, therefore the conversion from int.

To test it:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
  {
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (int) Bytes[i] << " ";
  }
```